# Wordpress DB LOST

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, parsing

I have a blog and currently has been lost. The company that hosts my blog had an issue with that server. And all MySQL Databases on that server has been lost (Helpfully i had a backup but it was from 2012). Never thought the server will crash and lost my data.

The good news is i've found the an archive (cached html version) of my blog on the web.archive.org

My great request is how can i get the data from there ? Does any one had that problem like me and found a solution and can share it here ?. Please it's very important to get the data back. (I know i can do a copy/paste from that site but it will take like for ever.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That cached version isn't going to contain all the necessary metadata for wordpress. That old backup from 2012 is unfortunately your best bet. Make offsite backups in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy answer here.

WordPress holds lots of meta data with each post, even on a default installation with no additional plugins.  All of that meta information has been lost.

You could, in theory, crawl the old web.archive.org version.  There are lots of tools to do this.  If you're using WordPress, then you're probably familiar with PHP, so something like [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) may be useful.  You would use it like so:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

The alternative is simply to copy and paste all of the past entries manually, which is, of course, time consuming.

I would suggest that whatever method you choose you implement your own backup solution and not rely on your hosts.  There are [lots of options on the WordPress plugins site](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=backup) or use a service such as [VaultPress](https://vaultpress.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer mikemike. I will take in consideration your answer and i will install an backup plugin.
Once again thanks for your help :D